# Start debugging mode in PyCharm after some part of the code has been executed

Tags: pycharm

when using the debugging mode in PyCharm I get an error after it executes a certain part of my code. The strange thing is that when executing this part in normal mode (without debugging) there is no error at all and the code does what it should do (and I can't explain at all why an error is thrown in debugging mode as there is nothing critical in the commands).

Anyways, I wanted to know if it is possible to tell PyCharm to execute the code in normal mode after a certain point and then start the debugging mode. This way I could't skip the 'critical part' (which is not critical at all in normal operation) and use the debugging mode afterwards.

**Reminder**: Is this not possible in PyCharm? It's really annoying as there is no bug in my code at this certain position but when executing the debug mode (for other issues) an error is thrown.

Comment: I recommend you to find the bug. You may see it just in debugging (for now), but it is a bug. Probably a time based bug, so on other machines (maybe the slowest one) will get it also on normal mode, or maybe an "heisenbug" (a bug which happens irregularly, the most difficult to track). You are in a good shape to find it because you have it consistently.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Thanks for your comment. I can tell you that I have been using the 'critical part' of the code for more than 1 year now and I have executed it on different machines. Never has it produced an error. It is a line from scikit learn about scaling input data. When executing in normal mode, I printed how the data looks before and after the line that throws the error. It has always been totally correct and the line exactly does what it should do (scale the data). Only when running in debug mode, I get a very strange error

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Thanks for your answer. Any comments on my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you as I strongly question your assumption "You may see it just in debugging (for now), but it is a bug".

Comment: I cannot comment further. I'm not an expert on Python debugging. In any case, either there is a bug in your code (maybe just assumption you take about Python), or in Python code or some library code. Try a different version of Python. (ask here a new question about that problem, maybe you will see known workaround). Real solution: it is difficult to tell you. You may just bypass some code (just for debugging, document it with e.g. `if not DEBUG_SKIP_INITIALIZATION:` (or something like that). Entering debug in middle of code (I think) it is difficult: interpreter didn't save useful info